# Uncover gnuplot graph on beamer slide

Tags: beamer, gnuplot

I have problems including a gnuplot graph in a beamer slide in which it should be visible at the very end of the slide, without all other elements on the slide.

The problem is, it seems I can't use `only` with a `gnuplottex` plot.

What I've tried so far is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usetheme{AnnArbor} %not my actual theme, just for MWE
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[subfolder,siunitx,cleanup]{gnuplottex}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Zeitschritt}

 Some text...

 \vfill

 \onslide<2-4>{
 \begin{block}{Zeitschritt als Funktion der Drehrate des Propellers}
  \begin{equation}
   fancy equation
  \end{equation}
  \onslide<3-4>{some text to go with it}
 \end{block}
 }

 \onslide<4>{
 \begin{block}{Rampenfunktion}
  \begin{equation}
   even more fancy equation
  \end{equation}
 \end{block} 
 }

\only<5>{
        \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
        set size 0.9,0.8

        min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
        max(a,b) = (a > b) ? a : b

        set yrange[0:6]
        set ylabel 'Timestep $\Delta t$ [\si{\degree\per\second}]'
        set xrange[0:5]
        set xlabel 'Time [\si{\second}]'
        set grid
        set key box right top spacing 1.3 samplen 3 width -5

        set style line 1 lw 3

        f(x)= x<1 ? 5 : 5-4*(sin(min(pi*(x-1)/(2*(4-1)),(pi/2))))**2
        g(x)= x<1 ? 5 : max(-1.33*x+6.33,1)

        plot f(x) ls 1 lc 2 t 'Rampenfunktion $\Delta t = 2...4$',\
        g(x) lc 1 t 'Lineare Rampenfunktion';

      \end{gnuplot}
      }

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

If you comment out the `\only<5>{` part, it works when compiling with `pdflatex --shell-escape`.

If you don't, LaTeX will tell you:

```
 Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete.
```

It seems, the `only` command turns off the `fragile` option for the frame, or simply ignores it, so I can't do a `gnuplot` plot here.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: my MWE should be compilable as it is. The part with the `gnuplot` plot is to be inserted somewhere in the `frame`. 
I don't really get your point, if you insert the `gnuplot` part, it throws the error.
I'll rebuild it a bit, so it shows my problems in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `onlyenv` could be your friend.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usetheme{AnnArbor} %not my actual theme, just for MWE
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[subfolder,siunitx,cleanup]{gnuplottex}


\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}[fragile]{Zeitschritt}

        Some text...

        \vfill

\begin{onlyenv}<1-4>



        \onslide<2-4>{
            \begin{block}{Zeitschritt als Funktion der Drehrate des Propellers}
                \begin{equation}
                fancy equation
                \end{equation}
                \onslide<3-4>{some text to go with it}
            \end{block}
        }

        \onslide<4>{
            \begin{block}{Rampenfunktion}
                \begin{equation}
                even more fancy equation
                \end{equation}
            \end{block} 
        }

\end{onlyenv}

\begin{onlyenv}<5>
            \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
                set size 0.9,0.8

                min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
                max(a,b) = (a > b) ? a : b

                set yrange[0:6]
                set ylabel 'Timestep $\Delta t$ [\si{\degree\per\second}]'
                set xrange[0:5]
                set xlabel 'Time [\si{\second}]'
                set grid
                set key box right top spacing 1.3 samplen 3 width -5

                set style line 1 lw 3

                f(x)= x<1 ? 5 : 5-4*(sin(min(pi*(x-1)/(2*(4-1)),(pi/2))))**2
                g(x)= x<1 ? 5 : max(-1.33*x+6.33,1)

                plot f(x) ls 1 lc 2 t 'Rampenfunktion $\Delta t = 2...4$',\
                g(x) lc 1 t 'Lineare Rampenfunktion';

            \end{gnuplot}
        \end{onlyenv}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know what the problem is precisely, the following seems to work: Replace `\only<5>{...}` by `\onslide+<5>` (without `{` and `}`):

```
\onslide+<5>

    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
    set size 0.9,0.8

    min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
    max(a,b) = (a > b) ? a : b

    set yrange[0:6]
    set ylabel 'Timestep $\Delta t$ [\si{\degree\per\second}]'
    set xrange[0:5]
    set xlabel 'Time [\si{\second}]'
    set grid
    set key box right top spacing 1.3 samplen 3 width -5

    set style line 1 lw 3

    f(x)= x<1 ? 5 : 5-4*(sin(min(pi*(x-1)/(2*(4-1)),(pi/2))))**2
    g(x)= x<1 ? 5 : max(-1.33*x+6.33,1)

    plot f(x) ls 1 lc 2 t 'Rampenfunktion $\Delta t = 2...4$',\
    g(x) lc 1 t 'Lineare Rampenfunktion';

  \end{gnuplot}
```

The '+' makes sure that the plot is invisible, and not transparent.
(Transparency does not really look good, though, since transparency basically only works with text, so part of the graph will always be fully visible.)

Comment: This is exactly the reason why I want to use `only`, because the  graph should replace the former content of the slide and should not be visible before `<5>`

Comment: The '+' makes it invisible instead of transparent.  By the way, if the graph should replace the former content, why don't you just start a new slide?  Also, you need to replace the other `\onslide`s by `\only`s, otherwise the text to be replaced does not vanish.